# I have a PPL in Australia and own a plane. I am wondering if I am legally allowed to hire my plane out to other pilots and make money?

Tags: ppl, australia, casa-regulations

I have found multiple answers that state I can lease to a school and things like that but I need to know if I can hire my plane out privately to other pilots (I.e mates) And actually make a profit from this. I won’t be flying it to make profit just through the hire costs. Note: I am in Australia and it’s an experimental (vans rv6)
Thanks!

Comment: I assume as you're in Australia you're interested in casa regs not faa regs (I've retagged as appropriate)

Comment: Ahh legend thank you. What are the rules where you’re located?

Comment: You can start off by consulting [this](https://www.casa.gov.au/aircraft/sport-aviation/amateur-built-and-experimental-aircraft) page.

Comment: In our area, the FAA rules allow you to rent or lease your own plane to other people or organizations. But, the plane would have to have standard category certification. So, an experimental like the Vans RV6 would not work. Also, you can not mix or share the flight time as a private pilot. That would put you in a gray area of flying for compensation. The problem would be with insurance. Will your policy allow it? They may require you to be in the aircraft as PIC at all times, or for you to do checkout flights with each client. Which would put you back in the gray area.

Comment: You could start your own non-equity flying club. Or, you could make the rental a commercial enterprise. Either way, I would not let anyone fly your plane while the plane is in your name as owner. Put the aircraft into a corporate entity name for liability purposes. Also, hire a CFI to perform checkout flights. I personally know of at least two people who have done this. One of which is a non-pilot who bought the aircraft for their aspiring pilot son. Now, they have grown to be a multi-plane flight school and rental company. Some of them leased from other pilots.